# Just want to make sure I'm doing things right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am planning on creating a website with one of my friends.  Both of us know next to 
nothing of coding and programming.  We are planning to display hundreds, potentially thousands
of images on this website. **These images will have a short description**, and will not be user uploaded, but we may potentially want to implement an option to save the favorite images.

There will be a button that randomizes the images shown (**one image at a time**). Users will click this button and it will randomize from all the images, displaying a new one on the screen **replacing the old one**.  Is it possible to write code that makes it so it will display a new random image, but not repeat the same image until it has cycled through all of the images (potentially thousands)?

Just from browsing the web, looking at tutorials, and reading some other stuff we've have a general idea of what needs to be done.  We need to **store the images as files on a server**, and **store the description of the images and file path on a database**. To create the button function we use javascript(?) and write a script that will randomize. Someone mentioned JSON but I don't know what that is.

Are we on the right track? We are both currently looking into **PHP**. Although we have a general idea of what needs to be done, we don't know where to start as far as tying this whole project together.We are trying to figure out how to start saving the images as files, and implementing them into the database but don't really know how.

tl;dr We would like some guidance on where to go with this, how we can possibly tie all of this together, and if we have the right idea of what to do.

Learning this stuff out of the blue can seem kind of overwhelming at first, that is why I'm extremely grateful for all the advice and answers.

Comment: It is like eating a real size chocolate elephant. Take it one bite at a time. See if you can `ftp` the image files to the server and create a page to show one of those images. Then dive into PHP and databases. Store the images paths and description and see if you can retrieve it, for just one image. And so on.

Comment: JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation is just a syntax for storing & exchanging data, it serves a similar purpose to XML if you are familiar with that.

Comment: Start by creating a static site with no javascript. Perhaps an "about us"link to learn html, then proceed to more complicated stuff.

Comment: Why not hire a programmer or outsource it to someone? You surely don't build a vehicle knowing it has 4 wheels and an engine.

Comment: @RST Thanks for the advice. I will try what you recommend. Just attempting to do it with one image at first seems smart. By "and so on" do you mean continue to do that with the other images as well? What would you recommend for creating a randomizer? Javascript?

P.S. We've made a static site, it has one picture in the middle, a black background, and some text. We figured out that basic HTML and CSS...

Comment: @Nordenheim We were considering that but it doesn't seem too complicated, the idea of this website is fairly simple actually. just a bit of effort and we could tag team it ourselves.. I hope.

Comment: You could go down the JavaScript route for the 'randomizer'. I'd recommend you first look into into arrays (used to store a collection, or list of items) to store your image URLS, then look into how to select and remove a random element (item) from the array.

Comment: With `and so on` I meant take it one step at a time. First with static image, then try getting information to/from database, then try randomized information, then try randomized but not duplicate. Focus on one step, wait for the next step until this step works. It will make searching for solutions easier and you will build knowledge of what you are doing in a structured way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me for leaving this as an answer. I don't have enough rep to leave it as a comment.

Programming is all about problem solving one step at a time. I'd suggest writing a basic list of all the things your program must do. For instance, in your case, the list may start like: 
1. Store img file path in database
2. Retrieve img path from database to display on webpage
3. Attach a description to img
4. Write code to randomize images
5. Write code to display images
6. Etc. etc.

Once you have this, you can start looking into which programming languages are best suited for the task. First each task, you'll usually have several options. For instance, you may decide on PHP or ASP.NET for tasks involving your server. Or JSON vs XML for handling data. I good place to browse basic language capabilities is w3schools.com. They provide pretty basic stuff that someone with no programming experience can understand. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: a programmer could only develop by gaining knowledge from others and sharing knowledge to others, So @wheresmyspaceship stack overflow is always ready to hear you and welcome

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to limit your technical needs quite a bit in my opinion.
As far as I have understood what you wanna do, you won't really need a server-side scripting language and you won't need a database neither.
And if you are totally new to programming then you would profit a lot on restricting yourselves to one programming language instead of having to learn three (for example `PHP`, `Javascript` and `MySQL`).

So you would "just" need to learn a bit of `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript`.
To store the images on your webserver, you just need some `FTP` client. You will need the FTP client or some editor with FTP client included to upload your HTML, CSS and Javascript files as well anyways.

To save the link or `url` to your images, you don't necessarily need a database. for example you can put all the images into your HTML code with `<img>` tags. you can initially hide them by `CSS`. Or you save the urls of your images by using Javascript arrays or objects (`JSON` means nothing else than JavaScript Object Notation).

All the logic can be done by `Javascript` itself. You can use it to randomize the images you wanna display plus to save the images a user already has seen.

**TL;DR:** I recommend that you restrict yourselves to "just" learning a bit of `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript`. Seems like everything you wanna do can be done without needing a server-side programming language or a database.

Comment: I have heard that is not a good idea with thousands of images though.